# Reference Repository Classes that utilizes a LinqToSql as ORM in a .Net Core Application

Tags: asp.net-core, orm, linq-to-sql

I have an existing solution that has the server as `.netcore v 2.1` and was calling an api to do all of the `CRUD` Operations, after a long discussion , i was required to remove these api calls with a direct call to a class library project that has  repository classes that utilizes `LinqToSql` as `ORM` -Know it is too old , but they want to utilize the existing infrastructure- have done the refactor and build with no error, when in run time i was encountered with an error stating that could not load file or assembly `system.data.linq version 4.0.0.0`

I am not sure but is this because the `.net core` could not utilize a library (i mean the `LinqToSql Orm library` )that is not in `.net standard v 1.0` or above or is it something else? i mean it is the other project that has it !
also another thing, i do not care for supporting linux so in case of any workaround that would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think u have to use ef core in core project

Comment: Yes. The functionality for LINQ to SQL comes from Entity Framework (Core or no), so you have to take a dependency on that, even if you aren't using the rest of EF.

Comment: what i am referring to is a whole ORM library that is too old , and that was found in .net 3.5 only https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/

it is not found in .net standard any version by the way